# Is there a certain number of lines of code to be followed /maintain?

Tags: c#, .net, programming-practices

I am developing a software system (Patient Administration System) and I have noticed it already had 451 lines of code(in one namespace).

Is this bad? Or does the number of lines of code not matter as long as the methods and comments are useful and they doing what they are intended to do?

Or there is a number of lines of code to maintain like a namespace should only have 500 lines of code something like that

Comment: 500 lines of code is almost nothing. I'm quite sure there are many *types* in the `System` namespace that have more than that.

Comment: I don't see how lines of code are relevant to a namespace.  If we were talking about a method, maybe.  But a namespace? Namespaces can contain hundreds or even thousands of classes.

Comment: Short answer: no. Do not use lines of code to determine when you should separate code, but do use it as an indicator that you might need to reevaluate your code and make sure your components are separated properly.

Answer (score 12):

The reason for line-number guidelines is that huge blocks of code is hard to read. This does not apply to namespaces as they themselves do not have any code to be read.

It is not at all uncommon to have thousands if not millions of lines inside a single namespace and so 500 is not at all a problem.

Instead of going by line number, ask yourself, "is this a separate, contained component?" If so, give a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is a number of lines of code to maintain like a namespace
>   should only have 500 lines of code ?

In general, we cannot be particular about the number of lines of code a namespace can hold as it depends on the classes defined in it.

That said, usually a collection of well defined classes are grouped into a particular namespace. So the key here is that one must be wise in defining  individual class which are apt for their functional role and not a collection of classes that come under one namespace which form the total lines for a given namespace.